# VkDescriptorSet overstepping dynamic UBO

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to implement a dynamic uniform buffer object to my project taking [this code](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/tree/master/examples/dynamicuniformbuffer) as an example. I'm new to the API, I have done the core of the program following [this tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Introduction). At the moment I'm stuck with this issue:

```
validation layer: VkDescriptorSet 0x42bf70000000032[] bound as set #0 encountered the following validation error at vkCmdDrawIndexed() time: Dynamic descriptor in binding #2 index 0 uses buffer 9A90CE000000002B with dynamic offset 768 combined with offset 0 and range 32000 that oversteps the buffer size of 32000.
```

The error occurs for every occurance from this for loop (from createCommandBuffers()) (except the first one) :

```
for (uint32_t j = 0; j < OBJECT_INSTANCES; j++)
        {
            uint32_t dynamicOffset = j * static_cast<uint32_t>(dynamicAlignment);
            std::cout << dynamicOffset << std::endl;
            vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSets[i], 1, &dynamicOffset);

            vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.size()), 1, 0, 0, 0);
            std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
        }
```

(dynamicOffset seems correct and get incremented well by 256)

I really don't see what I have done wrong.. Do someone has an idea?

How the VkDescriptorSets are created:

```
    void createDescriptorSets() {
    std::vector<VkDescriptorSetLayout> layouts(swapChainImages.size(), descriptorSetLayout);
    VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo allocInfo = {};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.descriptorPool = descriptorPool;
    allocInfo.descriptorSetCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(swapChainImages.size());
    allocInfo.pSetLayouts = layouts.data();

    descriptorSets.resize(swapChainImages.size());
    if (vkAllocateDescriptorSets(device, &allocInfo, descriptorSets.data()) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate descriptor sets!");
    }

    size_t dubo_size = OBJECT_INSTANCES * dynamicAlignment;

    std::cout << dubo_size << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < swapChainImages.size(); i++) {
        VkDescriptorBufferInfo uniformBufferInfo = {};
        uniformBufferInfo.buffer = uniformBuffers[i];
        uniformBufferInfo.offset = 0;
        uniformBufferInfo.range = sizeof(UniformBufferObject);

        VkDescriptorImageInfo imageInfo{};
        imageInfo.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
        imageInfo.imageView = textureImageView;
        imageInfo.sampler = textureSampler;

        VkDescriptorBufferInfo dynamicUniformBufferInfo = {};
        dynamicUniformBufferInfo.buffer = dynamicUniformBuffers[i];
        dynamicUniformBufferInfo.offset = 0;
        dynamicUniformBufferInfo.range = dubo_size;

        std::array<VkWriteDescriptorSet, 3> descriptorWrites{};

        descriptorWrites[0].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
        descriptorWrites[0].dstSet = descriptorSets[i];
        descriptorWrites[0].dstBinding = 0;
        descriptorWrites[0].dstArrayElement = 0;
        descriptorWrites[0].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
        descriptorWrites[0].descriptorCount = 1;
        descriptorWrites[0].pBufferInfo = &uniformBufferInfo;

        descriptorWrites[1].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
        descriptorWrites[1].dstSet = descriptorSets[i];
        descriptorWrites[1].dstBinding = 1;
        descriptorWrites[1].dstArrayElement = 0;
        descriptorWrites[1].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
        descriptorWrites[1].descriptorCount = 1;
        descriptorWrites[1].pImageInfo = &imageInfo;

        descriptorWrites[2].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
        descriptorWrites[2].dstSet = descriptorSets[i];
        descriptorWrites[2].dstBinding = 2;
        descriptorWrites[2].dstArrayElement = 0;
        descriptorWrites[2].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC;
        descriptorWrites[2].descriptorCount = 1;
        descriptorWrites[2].pBufferInfo = &dynamicUniformBufferInfo;

        vkUpdateDescriptorSets(device, static_cast<uint32_t>(descriptorWrites.size()), descriptorWrites.data(), 0, nullptr);

    }
}
```

How the buffers are created:

```
    void createDynamicUniformBuffers()
{
    VkPhysicalDeviceProperties prop;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(physicalDevice, &prop);
    size_t minUboAlignment = prop.limits.minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment;
    dynamicAlignment = sizeof(glm::mat4);
    if (minUboAlignment > 0) {
        dynamicAlignment = (dynamicAlignment + minUboAlignment - 1) & ~(minUboAlignment - 1);
    }

    VkDeviceSize bufferSize = OBJECT_INSTANCES * dynamicAlignment;

    uboDataDynamic.model = (glm::mat4*)alignedAlloc(bufferSize, dynamicAlignment);
    assert(uboDataDynamic.model);

    std::cout << "minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment = " << minUboAlignment << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dynamicAlignment = " << dynamicAlignment << std::endl;

    dynamicUniformBuffers.resize(swapChainImages.size());
    dynamicUniformBuffersMemory.resize(swapChainImages.size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < swapChainImages.size(); i++) {
        createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, dynamicUniformBuffers[i], dynamicUniformBuffersMemory[i]);
    }

}
```

And finally and bit more of the terminal:

```
minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment = 256
dynamicAlignment = 256
32000
0
done
256
validation layer: VkDescriptorSet 0x42bf70000000032[] bound as set #0 encountered the following validation error at vkCmdDrawIndexed() time: Dynamic descriptor in binding #2 index 0 uses buffer 9A90CE000000002B with dynamic offset 256 combined with offset 0 and range 32000 that oversteps the buffer size of 32000.
done
512
validation layer: VkDescriptorSet 0x42bf70000000032[] bound as set #0 encountered the following validation error at vkCmdDrawIndexed() time: Dynamic descriptor in binding #2 index 0 uses buffer 9A90CE000000002B with dynamic offset 512 combined with offset 0 and range 32000 that oversteps the buffer size of 32000.
done
768
validation layer: VkDescriptorSet 0x42bf70000000032[] bound as set #0 encountered the following validation error at vkCmdDrawIndexed() time: Dynamic descriptor in binding #2 index 0 uses buffer 9A90CE000000002B with dynamic offset 768 combined with offset 0 and range 32000 that oversteps the buffer size of 32000.
done
1024
validation layer: VkDescriptorSet 0x42bf70000000032[] bound as set #0 encountered the following validation error at vkCmdDrawIndexed() time: Dynamic descriptor in binding #2 index 0 uses buffer 9A90CE000000002B with dynamic offset 1024 combined with offset 0 and range 32000 that oversteps the buffer size of 32000.
done
1280
validation layer: VkDescriptorSet 0x42bf70000000032[] bound as set #0 encountered the following validation error at vkCmdDrawIndexed() time: Dynamic descriptor in binding #2 index 0 uses buffer 9A90CE000000002B with dynamic offset 1280 combined with offset 0 and range 32000 that oversteps the buffer size of 32000.
done
```

Comment: "*`uniformBufferInfo.range = sizeof(UniformBufferObject);`*" What is this doing? How big is your `VkBuffer`? And why are you setting the dynamic UBO's side to the same size as the buffer you created in the other code?

Comment: Turns out that using dynamicUniformBufferInfo.range = VK_WHOLE_SIZE to give the buffer's rang fixed the problem :)  Thanks

Comment: Answers go in the "Post Your Anaswer" section. It's 100% OK to answer your own question, but we don't want answers *within* questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Fix:** The range given to the *VkDescriptorBufferInfo* for the dynamic UBO was the issue. Works out when using `dynamicUniformBufferInfo.range = VK_WHOLE_SIZE` instead.